# How to retrive top menu html for all stores using cron

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, topmenu

I need to get the top menu html is cron job and need to save it in the db.
I used the the same functionalities as in the core to get the top menu in my cron job function.
But the problem is I need to top menu for each store.

Below is the core function specifying the menu

`$this->_menu = new Varien_Data_Tree_Node(array(), 'root', new Varien_Data_Tree());`

Is there a way to set the particular store and the respective topmenu html?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use environment emulation of the specified store

```
$appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');

//Start environment emulation of the specified store
$initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId);

/*
 * Any code thrown here will be executed as we are currently running that store
 * with applied locale, design and similar
 */

//Stop environment emulation and restore original store
$appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);
```